# all-the-icons not working correctly (already ran all-the-icons-install-fonts)

Tags: linux, fonts, emacs, gentoo

I am currently running emacs on Gentoo linux. My intention was to use all-the-icons ivy (I also downloaded all-the-icons-ivy). Unfortunately, all the icons come out confusing.
I have already run all-the-icons-install-fonts, per the wiki instructions. Does anyone know what is happening?

[image]

Comment: Are you running Emacs using its GUI or via a terminal emulator? Did you also follow the instructions which say to run `fc-cache -f -v`?

Comment: I have tried it in the 2 ways but it does not work and of course I have executed that command but everything remains the same

Answer (score 0):

You may lack the fonts for all-the-icons.

The all-the-icons [documentation](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el/#installing-fonts) recommends installing the fonts by running this command in Emacs:
`M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts`.

Alternatively, you can try installing the fonts using the package manager for your OS. For Gentoo, there's a package for all-the-icons [here](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/app-emacs/all-the-icons/changelog).

I ran into a similar issue on an Arch based distro, and was able to resolve it by installing all-the-iconts. For those using Arch based distros, the package can be found [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-all-the-icons).